# Best way to list down the elements of group generated by a cycle?

Tags: group-theory, soft-question, finite-groups

> **Def :** Let $G =\langle (123\cdots n)\rangle$ be a group generated by cycle $(123\cdots n)$.

I want to enumerated (list down all of its elements). I tried on small example $G =\langle (123 )\rangle$, In this group elements are $\{id,(123),(132)\}$.

In general i.e. for $G =\langle (123\cdots n)\rangle$, $G=\{id,(123\cdots n) ,(n\cdots 21),(135\cdots n-1),(246\cdots n),\}$ and their inverses will also be there. How many I am missing?

**Question :** What is the best way (so that I did not miss any) to enumerate the elements in this case?

Comment: A power of a cycle permutation of size $n$ need not be another cycle of size $n$. For example, $(1\;2\;3\;4)^2 = (1\;3)(2\;4)$.

Comment: Since for example $ \( 3 \ 5 \ 6 \ 1 \)\( 2 \ 4 \) = \( 4 \ 2 \)\( 5 \ 6 \ 1 \ 3 \) $, you should be extra careful not to "double count" any permutations. I suggest adopting some systematic way of writing out your permutations (in cycle notation). One way is this: a) Start every cycle with its smallest item. b) Order the cycles in the permutation in increasing order of their first items. Using these rules, the above permutation would be $ \( 1 \ 3 \ 5 \ 6 \)\( 2 \ 4 \) $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check that you have all the elements of the group generated by $(123\cdots n)$ because there are exactly $n$ of them; $\langle(123\cdots n)\rangle$ is the cyclic group of order $n$, so you can just count them.

The **form** of the elements can be a little tricky when when $n$ is not prime. Let me exhibit the groups for $n = 4$ and $n = 5$ so you you can see the difference. The element $(123\cdots n)$ is the generator; the elements that follow it in my list are its powers in order. Thus $(1234)^2=(13)(24)$. After studying my examples, you might want to try $n = 6$ for yourself.

For $n=4$, $G=${$id, (1234), (13)(24), (1432)$}  (I begin each element with
 $1$ making it easier to keep track of them.)

For $n=5$, $G=${$id, (12345), (13524), (14253), (15432)$}

Comment: What do you mean by all the elements in the first line?

Comment: @sssss All the elements of the group generated by $(123...n)$. There are $n$ of them. It is the cyclic group of order $n$.

Comment: Please add more detail.

Comment: @sssss I have added some detail but I'm not sure what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Stephen's answer:

Notice that $g=(1,\ldots,n)$ is the map $x\mapsto x+1$ (mod $n$).

Therefore $g^i$ is the map $x\mapsto x+i$ (mod $n$), so is $$(1,i+1,2i+1,\ldots)(2,2+i,\ldots)\cdots({\rm hcf}(n,i),\ldots)$$

This should make it very easy to list the powers of $g$ (and therefore enumerate $\langle g\rangle$).